# Proofs in number theory that involve non-standard models of arithmetic

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, model-theory

While reading an introductory text on model theory, I found it interesting that one can reformulate the famous conjectures about twin primes and Mersenne primes in terms of non-standard models of arithmetic:

> The twin prime conjecture is true if and only if there is some non-standard model of arithmetic $\mathcal{M}$ and at least one pair of non-standard twin primes in $\mathcal{M}$.

> There are infinitely many Mersenne primes if and only if there is a non-standard Mersenne prime.

My question is this: Are there any examples of longstanding open questions in number theory whose eventual solution took the above form, that is, as an implication of some feature of a non-standard model of arithmetic? I would be particularly interested to know of any instances where the only known proof of a certain result makes use of this strategy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What introductory text have you read?

Comment: @JoelAdler "An Invitation to Model Theory" by Jonathan Kirby. It's an undergraduate-level introduction and I am by no means an expert on the subject. The statements appear as Proposition 13.11 and Exercise 13.5 in the text.

Comment: Even if you include all of mathematics and not just number theory, there are not very many examples of conjectures being proved for the first time using nonstandard methods; see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/16312/) for more info. Your examples above are basically straightforward applications of a transfer principle; the transfer principle is not very "deep," and so cannot be expected to help too much with solving a very hard problem. Any proof using a transfer principle can be rewritten without it, so in some sense it can't play an "essential" role in a proof.

Comment: For “questions which can be stated arithmetically” rather than just “questions in number theory”, the answer might be yes. Eg: One might use non-standard models to prove that any sentence in $S$ which follows from theory $T$ also follows from theory $U$. Proof theorists who know about models of arithmetic might be able to provide examples.

Comment: @Menander I Seen only now, thanks!